# Create Azure Role using Azure Cli though Powershell scripts return error

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, azure-cli

I'm trying to create a ps1 script to automate assign a role withing Azure for my application. I assign each information into a variable, but I get an error when I run the `az role assignment` create through the variables. Below is my script:

```
$objIdApp = ((az ad sp list -o json) | ConvertFrom-Json) | where {$_.appDisplayName -eq "aplicationname"} | Select-Object -Property objectId | Out-String
$aksId = (az aks list -o json | ConvertFrom-Json) | where {$_.name -eq "aksname"} | Select-Object -Property id | Out-String
az role assignment create --assignee ($objIdApp --scope $aksId  --role "Contributor"
```

I get the error below from az:

```
az role assignment create: error: the following arguments are required: --role
```

However, if I get each string value, substitute the variable with the string, and execute it, it works. How can I fix this so that I can use the variables?

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose, you just need to use Azure CLI with the output parameter `-o tsv`, then the output is also a string. The script will like below:

```
$appId = az ad sp list --display-name appName --query [0].appId -o tsv
$appId.GetType()
$aksId = az aks show -g charlesContainer -n aksName--query id -o tsv
$aksId.GetType()
az role assignment create --assignee $appId --scope $aksId --role "Contributor"
```

The screenshot of the result will like this:

[image]